# MATLAB: varargin (cell) not compatible with fminsearch (double)?

Tags: matlab

I have functions I've built using variable arguments but now I want to optimize these functions. However, in the current form, varargin doesn't seem to work well with FMINSEARCH? What can I do? Is there something wrong?

I am trying to do the following:

```
y = @(varargin)-fn_backtest_v0002(varargin{:}); 
start = {3,0,0.5,10,0.05,0,1,1};    
max = fminsearch(y,start);
```

But I get this error:

```
Error using fminsearch (line 96)
FMINSEARCH only accepts inputs of data type double.
```

From the simple examples of FMINSEARCH, a vector should be used, however I have varargin in my functions which require arguments to be of cell type.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a wrapper function that accepts vector as parameter and passes them in the format that `fn_backtest_v0002` expects to get. For example:

```
 function out = fn_backtest_v0002(varargin)
     .... %Your code here
 end
```

And the wrapper function:

```
 function out = fn_backtest_v0002_wrapper(vec)
     out = -fn_backtest_v0002(num2cell(vec));
 end
```

Then, you can use the wrapper function with `fminsearch` :

```
start = [3,0,0.5,10,0.05,0,1,1];    
max = fminsearch(y,@fn_backtest_v0002_wrapper);
```

---

Another alternative is to re-write `fn_backtest_v0002` to have vector input arguments (Which makes much more sense than `varargin` in your case.

Comment: +1 for recommendation to rewrite the function to use a vector input instead of varargin

Comment: Your wrapper idea worked. I couldn't get your exact code to work but I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andrey for idea of wrapper function. (I am a programming newbie).

This is exactly how I did it.

Create wrapper function:

```
function [ out ] = fn_backtest_v0002_wrapper( vec )
cell = num2cell(vec);
out = fn_backtest_v0002(cell{:});
end
```

Then I can run the following commands successfully:

```
y = @(vec)-fn_backtest_v0002_wrapper(vec);
start = [3,0,0.5,10,0.05,0,1,1];
max = fminsearch(y,start);
```